Serial console: How can I switch off automatic login?
I've got a cluster of four nodes running Debian Bullseye. All of them are connected to a controller board via a UART for admin purposes. The control board uses picocom to access the serial console of the respective node.
Now I've got an issue: When typing exit, the respective node logs me back in and starts a new shell immediately. I also get the root shell without having to type in username and password.
Apparently, an instance of agetty is providing the shell:
root@blade3n2:~# ps -ef | grep getty
root        1127       1  0 18:27 tty1     00:00:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty1 linux
root        1836    1646  0 18:35 ttyFIQ0  00:00:00 grep getty

As this is a security flaw to me, I'd like to switch off this behavior, so that…

…I'll have to log in with user name and password each time I connect to one of the nodes, and…
…I'll get disconnected and picocom closed when a session is closed (with an exit or somehow else).

UPDATE: After receiving some advice, I did some diagnostics:
root@blade3n1:~# ps -fwwwC agetty
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root        1121       1  0 20:55 tty1     00:00:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty1 linux

root@blade3n1:~# pstree -ap 1121
agetty,1121 -o -p -- \\u --noclear tty1 linux

root@blade3n1:~# grep -r ttyFIQ0 /etc

root@blade3n1:~# systemctl cat serial-getty@ttyFIQ0.service
# /lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Serial Getty on %I
Documentation=man:agetty(8) man:systemd-getty-generator(8)
Documentation=http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html
BindsTo=dev-%i.device
After=dev-%i.device systemd-user-sessions.service plymouth-quit-wait.service ge>
After=rc-local.service

# If additional gettys are spawned during boot then we should make
# sure that this is synchronized before getty.target, even though
# getty.target didn't actually pull it in.
Before=getty.target
IgnoreOnIsolate=yes

# IgnoreOnIsolate causes issues with sulogin, if someone isolates
# rescue.target or starts rescue.service from multi-user.target or
# graphical.target.
Conflicts=rescue.service
Before=rescue.service

[Service]
# The '-o' option value tells agetty to replace 'login' arguments with an
# option to preserve environment (-p), followed by '--' for safety, and then
# the entered username.
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin root --noclear %I $TER
#ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 %I $TERM
Type=idle
Restart=always
UtmpIdentifier=%I
TTYPath=/dev/%I
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes
KillMode=process
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
SendSIGHUP=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=getty.target


I didn't say it must by agetty. I only added the output of ps for reference.

The grep getty command in your ps -ef | grep getty command output is apparently running on something called ttyFIQ0. The tty1 would typically be a virtual console on some kind of GPU, and even if it was a serial port, the agetty process is only present on it when that serial port is logged out: it gets replaced by the login session, and when the session ends, the init system will detect the process on that TTY has died and will spawn a new one. What will you find if you run grep -r ttyFIQ0 /etc? How about systemctl cat serial-getty@ttyFIQ0.service ?

@aviro I've just done what you had suggested. See the updated question.

The output of systemctl cat serial-getty@ttyFIQ0.service seems incomplete. It is normally displayed using less, so perhaps you copied only the first page of it. Run the command again and press space to see more. If that's really all, please run systemctl cat serial-getty@.service to also view the service template used by the serial-getty@ttyFIQ0.service instance.

Yes, apparently cat called less once the output didn't fit into the terminal window.

systemctl cat just means "display the definition of this systemd unit". Despite the name of the subcommand, it does not involve the actual cat command. If its output is not redirected to a pipe or a file, it uses the $SYSTEMD_PAGER or $PAGER if defined, or less by default.

It seems that your service file, /lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service, was edited, and the --autologin flag was added.
The name of this flag is pretty self explanatory in my opinion, but see the man pages of agetty for more details.
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin root --noclear %I $TER
#ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 %I $TERM

Edit this file, remove the first ExecStart line, remove the comment from the second ExecStart line, and run systemctl daemon-reload to reread the configuration file.
Then exit your autologin shell, and you shouldn't see a new one.
You didn't see it in your ps, because as @telecoM stated in the comments:

[...] the agetty process is only present on it when that serial port
is logged out: it gets replaced by the login session, and when the
session ends, the init system will detect the process on that TTY has
died and will spawn a new one.


So I've been searching for a needle in the haystack, right?!  The Debian distro came in fact preconfigured by the computer's manufacturer (who even said that the auto-login feature was intentional).

@Neppomuk I guess so, yes. I don't remember I've ever seen a distro that comes with autologin configured by default, since it's a security risk.

Semms to be a good idea, but when issuing systemctl daemon-reload, I get such a message: systemd-fstab-generator[2066]: Ignoring "noauto" for root device. Good or bad?
